# Unexpected data \r\n with Carbon laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I'm trying to get all of the students from a table using "Student::all()". I don't even have carbon in this function. It's not getting students by date or anything. When i try to run the function, I get the error shown in the picture. It's pointing to a carbon file in the vendor folder but I don't know what to change. The data from the database pulls fine in every other function of the program, just not this one exact thing. When I die/dump my function call,I get the students list just fine. Something is simply irritating Carbon for no apparent reason. If I use a carbon parameter, it works, the function doesn't stall, but it does not return the correct data even though the field in the database holds that info. Why would a line break be causing this issue?

[image: error screen shot]

[image: dd screen shot]

This function does not produce the error, but it does not result in the correct data.

```
public function exportRoster(){

$students = Student::whereDate('updated_at', Carbon::today())->get();
$pdf = PDF::loadView('printRoster', compact('students'), [], ['orientation' => 'L']);
return $pdf->stream('roster'.Carbon::today().'.pdf');

}
```

This function would obviously have the right data, but it produces the error of "Unexpected data".

```
public function exportRoster(){

$students = Student::all();
$pdf = PDF::loadView('printRoster', compact('students'), [], ['orientation' => 'L']);
return $pdf->stream('roster.pdf');

}
```

Just in case it helps, i've also included a screen shot of my database[image]

Here is the table i'm using with my students variable in the printRoster view. If I remove this table, all queries work.

```
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <th align = "left">Student Name</th>
      <th align = "left">Student ID</th>
      <th align = "left">District</th>
      <th align = "left">School</th>
      <th align = "left">Test Date/Time</th>
      <th align = "left">Vision</th>
      <th align = "left">Color</th>
      <th>Nurse</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($students as $student)
      @php
        $grade = array('20/40', '20/50', '20/60', '20/80', '20/100', '20/200', '20/400');
      @endphp
    <tr>
      <td>{{$student->fname.' '.$student->lname}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->student_number}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->district}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->school}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->updated_at}}</td>
      @if(in_array($student->od_dist, $grade) || in_array($student->os_dist, $grade) || in_array($student->ou_dist, $grade))
      <td>Failed</td>
    @else
      <td>
        Passed
      </td>
    @endif

      <td>{{$student->ou_color}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->nurse}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
  </table>
```

Comment: can you add code for printRoster view?

Comment: @Nagesh, i've updated my question to include it

Comment: Please try with date(Y-m-d H:i:s'', strtotime($student->updated_at))

Comment: So it should be Student::date(Y-m-d H:i:s'', strtotime($student->updated_at)) ?

Comment: No, it is date(Y-m-d H:i:s'', strtotime($student->updated_at)). date is the PHP function.

Comment: But where do I add that in my eloquent query?

Comment: Please add this in your view file.

Comment: ` @foreach($students as $student)
   
    <tr>
      <td>{{$student->fname.' '.$student->lname}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->student_number}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->district}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->school}}</td>
      <td>date(Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime({{$student->updated_at}}))</td>
      
      <td>{{$student->ou_color}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->nurse}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
`
This still gives the same error

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `updated_at` column is a timestamp so maybe you need to convert it in a raw date in order to show it. Please try if it works

```
@foreach($students as $student)
      @php
        $grade = array('20/40', '20/50', '20/60', '20/80', '20/100', '20/200', '20/400');
      @endphp
    <tr>
      <td>{{$student->fname.' '.$student->lname}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->student_number}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->district}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->school}}</td>
      <td>{{date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($student->updated_at))}}</td>
      @if(in_array($student->od_dist, $grade) || in_array($student->os_dist, $grade) || in_array($student->ou_dist, $grade))
      <td>Failed</td>
    @else
      <td>
        Passed
      </td>
    @endif

      <td>{{$student->ou_color}}</td>
      <td>{{$student->nurse}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Edit

```
public function exportRoster(){

    $students = Student::all();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('printRoster', $students);
    $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream('roster.pdf');    
}
```

Comment: i copy/pasted your code into my view. It still returns the same error. "Unexpected data. \r\n in view"